# Disable Add to Cart button when the Price is zero with jquery by adding class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have already search through stackoverflow from top to bottom no answer was found.

Note: its add to cart button but i changed the text to "place order"
I am trying to disable to add to cart button like adding a class to it to disable the button because if i hide the button it will also hide the checkboxes above which are attached with add to cart button.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXPEQ.png)
but its not working for me, its not disabling the button when price gets $0 maybe its the code or any other conflict.
here is the jquery code i am adding to wordpress head in theme editor and calling through

```
 <body onload="hideCart()">
```

and the jquery code is

```
<script>
function hideCart() {
    var value = jQuery('.price').text();
    if(value === '$0') {
        jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass("disable");
    } else { 
        jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').removeClass("disable");
    }
}
</script>
```

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEzXd.png)

Comment: If you dont want add to cart button either remove price or set stock to 0 with no backorders. If you want jquery make sure you hook to proper woo event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the correct class is `disabled`.  After changing that, it works on my machine.

If that doesn't work, have you debugged it yet?  Go to a product page, open your developer console (F12 on Chrome, go to Console tab), type the following, and press Enter:

```js
var value = jQuery('.price').text();
console.log(value);
```

You should see the price text.  From there you can test it further.

But, like Martin says, the proper way is to [enqueue your JavaScript file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/), and, for variations, add an eventListener on the `show_variation` event.  For simple files you current code should do the job, after fixing the class name.

Comment: Thank You. actually the value was $0$0 and i was matching it with $0.

Comment: No problem.  Could you please accept this answer?  Thanks.